# Getting values from child widget forms to Parent in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have several form fields created as separate child widgets and the submit action should be carried out from the parent widget.I have parent widget with "Applicant name" while I have "Applicant address and info" in the child widget.They are to be displayed in the same parent page, but how do I get the values from the child widget and then submit the whole form along with the parent widget.Thank you

Comment: Try passing a callback function to your child widget

Comment: You need an InheritedWidget, check https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html and https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/flutter-using-inheritedwidget-examples

Comment: Thanks  , I am using callback for some submit options and for some I am using state methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using TextFormField in the child widget you can simply pass TextEditingController from the parent widget to the child. Then use it like this

```
TextFormField(
 controller: widget.controller
 ....
```

And you can real text from the text form field using a controller.text

Comment: yes, I am using this method and it works.. thank you